# Navigation problem in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am making an application in which i make a super class for fetching data from the server 
and in that class i check the response and depending on the response push to different view but its not working.

I have first controller where when user click then--

```
DataViewController *obj=[[DataViewController alloc] init];

[obj FetchData];
```

This code in DataViewController:

```
Fetchdata()
{
    //Code for fetching data which is working fine.

    if([loginStatus isEqualToString:@"-1"] == YES) {

    } else {
        WebViewController *webview = [[WebViewController alloc] init]; 

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:webview animated:YES];
        [webview release]; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: We're going to need to see more of the code gluing those two bits together. As far as that stuff goes, it all seems fine. I notice you're not loading a .xib for your WebViewController--I assume you build its view programmatically in its `-loadView` method?

Comment: I create xib for WebViewController if u want to see the fetch data code then its here-

Comment: if([loginStatus isEqualToString:@"-1"]==YES)
 {   
 }
 else
 {
  WebViewController *webview = [[WebViewController alloc] init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:webview animated:YES];
  [webview release];
 }

Comment: How is the value of `loginStatus` derived?

Comment: Please use the curlybrace-button when you add code to your posts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer to my comment above, I surmise that you're not loading your `WebViewController` properly.

Try this:

```
WebViewController *webView = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TheNameofTheNib" bundle:nil];
```

That said, I still don't know whether the parts of your code you've posted are all in places where they're being called properly. Individually, they're syntactically correct, but there's more to life than syntax.

Comment: Okay, well, show more code then. I don't trust you're actually running your navigation stuff.